# Using left with charindex in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that has a description column and I want to select the distinct first word. This is the SQL I would use:

```
select distinct left(description,charindex(' ',description)-1)  from tableA
```

How would I convert this to LINQ query syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution

```
var result = tableA.Select(item => item.description.Split()[0]).Distinct();
```

Comment: This causes the error "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." when I use result.ToList();

Comment: @user1024941: I don't have access to Windows machine at the moment and wrote my answer from general LINQ knowledge. Does my answer fail too?

Comment: I made a slight modification, and this fails
var result = db.tableA.Select(item => item.description.Split()[0]).Distinct();

Comment: @user1024941: Right. because it is `description` column that you want to work on. Updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ to Entities, you can use [DbFunctions.Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.left(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Left(System.String,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int64%7D)) in combination with [String.IndexOf Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) (supported according to [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx)) like this

```
var result = db.TableA
    .Select(r => DbFunctions.Left(r.Description, r.Description.IndexOf(" ")))
    .Distinct();
```